# Vector Calculus Proof of Integration

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces, gaussian-integral, stokes-theorem

Let R be a solid region bounded by an oriented closed suface $\partial{R}$. Let f and g be $c^2$ scalar functions. Let the $\hat{n}$ be the outward normal to $\partial{R}$. Prove that

$$\iiint \nabla{f} \cdot{} \nabla{g} \ dV = \iint_{\partial{R}} f\nabla{g}\cdot{}d\vec{S} - \iiint_{R} f \nabla{}^2g \ dV$$

I am aware that the process to prove this is to use Gauss theorem on the RHS and that should somehow allow me to show the LHS, but I am not sure how to even begin this problem since f and g aren't given to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remember that

$$
\nabla\cdot(f {\bf F}) = \nabla f \cdot {\bf F} + f\nabla\cdot{\bf F} \tag{1}
$$

Now use ${\bf F} = \nabla g$ to find

$$
\nabla\cdot(f \nabla g) = \nabla f \cdot {\nabla g} + f\nabla\cdot{\nabla g} = \nabla f \cdot \nabla g + f \nabla^2 g \tag{2}
$$

Integrating at both sides

$$
\iiint_R \nabla\cdot(f\nabla g) {\rm d}V = \iiint_R \nabla f\cdot \nabla g {\rm d}V + \iiint_R f\nabla^2 g {\rm d}V \tag{3}
$$

Now apply the divergence theorem to the L.H.S

$$
\iint_{\partial R} f\nabla g \cdot{\rm d}{\bf S} = \iiint_R \nabla f\cdot \nabla g {\rm d}V + \iiint_R f\nabla^2 g {\rm d}V \tag{4}
$$

Comment: Thanks you so much for that.

Comment: @IsithaSubasinghe You are very welcome!